# Find A Cell Value in Sheet 1 and see if value exists in Column of Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a doc to confirm if specific values exist, in a specific order of text documents.

Essentially what I am trying to determine, is if a String Value from Cell B2 on Sheet 1(Campaign) exists inside of a column of String values on Sheet 2(Master List).

If the String Value Does exist then the Cell should highlight Green, IF it doesn't then Highlight Red, Then move down to the next Column value on Sheet 1 (i.e. B3) if any

I know I have to use for loops, but not 100% sure of the specific functions to employ within the loop

Any assistance you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all.

The Closest I have come up with

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Sheets("Master List")
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Set WS1 = Sheets("Campaign")

For i = 2 To 100
  For j = 2 to 100
' Loop through the Master sheet
      If WS1.Cells(i, 2) = WS.Cells(i, 2) Then
         ' If a match is found update color:
               Selection.Interior
               .Pattern = xlSolid
               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
               .Color = 5287936
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .PatternTintAndShade = 0
      Else If WS1.Cells(i, 2) <> WS.Cells(i, 2) Then
         ' If cell doesn't match is found update color:
               Selection.Interior
               .Pattern = xlSolid
               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
               .Color = 5287936
               .TintAndShade = 0
               .PatternTintAndShade = 0
     End if
  Next j  
Next i
```

Comment: This is easily doable with conditional formatting, no need for VBA. If you do need VBA, then use only one loop through the range on the Campaign sheet, with `Application.Match` or `Range.Find` to attempt to find a corresponding cell on the Master List sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Highlight Matching Cells

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightCampaign()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Master List")
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Range("B2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Campaign")
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dws.Range("B2", dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)) Then
            dCell.Interior.Color = 14348258 ' Green
        Else
            dCell.Interior.Color = 14083324 ' Red
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    MsgBox "Campaign values highlighted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If this has to be VBA, then something like this should work for you:

```
Sub FindValues()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsCmpn As Worksheet:    Set wsCmpn = wb.Worksheets("Campaign")
    Dim wsMstr As Worksheet:    Set wsMstr = wb.Worksheets("Master List")
    Dim rFindValues As Range:   Set rFindValues = wsCmpn.Range("B2", wsCmpn.Cells(wsCmpn.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    If rFindValues.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub    'No values to find
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rGreen As Range
    Dim rRed As Range
    
    'xlWhole for exact match
    'xlPart for partial match
    Dim lMatchType As Long: lMatchType = xlWhole
    
    For Each rCell In rFindValues.Cells
        If Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then 'Ignore blanks
            Set rFound = wsMstr.Columns("B").Find(rCell.Value, , xlValues, lMatchType, MatchCase:=False)
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Select Case (rRed Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rRed = rCell
                    Case Else:  Set rRed = Union(rRed, rCell)
                End Select
            Else
                Select Case (rGreen Is Nothing)
                    Case True:  Set rGreen = rCell
                    Case Else:  Set rGreen = Union(rGreen, rCell)
                End Select
                Set rFound = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell
    
    rFindValues.EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    If Not rRed Is Nothing Then rRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
    If Not rGreen Is Nothing Then rGreen.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Didn't know this for a long time: there is no need to reset with `Set rFound = Nothing` because if `Find` doesn't find, it sets the variable to `Nothing` on its own.